# In Java, how is an Array of objects garbage collected?

Tags: java, arrays, object, garbage-collection

When an array of objects is not referenced anymore, does the objects in that array are garbage collected too? (assuming no variables are referencing the elements)

In this page, http://java.sys-con.com/node/37613
it says - 
"The biggest danger is placing an object into a collection and forgetting to remove it. The memory used by that object will never be reclaimed."

If you make sure to nullify the references, why will that memory be unclaimed?

Thanks

Comment: Because if you don't nullify the references, it won't be reclaimed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When an array of objects is not referenced anymore, does the objects
>   in that array are garbage collected too? (assuming no variables are
>   referencing the elements)

Yes.

> "The biggest danger is placing an object into a collection and
>   forgetting to remove it. The memory used by that object will never be
>   reclaimed."

This is when you *are* holding a reference to the collection. For example, if you have a `Map` in which you put a key-value and then forget to remove then it stays there for ever. Think http sessions, if you use something in `ServerContext` or some such at start of request using session id as key but fail to remove it at end of the request processing..

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, the answer is yes, absolutely: the objects inside non-referenced array and no other references do get garbage collected.

As for the second question, the document talks about placing forgetting an object inside a *referenced* collection, for example a cache of some sort, a static field, a thread-local store, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be unclaimed if nothing references it. The article says that if you nullify a reference, but the object is still in a referenced collection (hence referenced), it won't be collected.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, anything that's not referenced is garbage collected.  So, yes, those objects would be garbage collected.

Also, note that:

1. An array is not a collection.
2. I think that what the person that wrote that meant was make sure you
   remember all of the places you're referencing an object, so that if
   you intend to remove it, it gets removed (and there are no lingering
   references to it).