# Does an ArrayList have to be set to null before assigning it another new array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, memory, memory-management

I have an array called mHomeworks. For onResume, I call:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((HomeworkAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    mHomeworks = HomeworkLab.get(getActivity()).getHomework();//update list
}
```

in regards to memory management, should I call:

```
    mHomeworks.removeAll(mHomeworks);
    mHomeworks = null;
```

Comment: **If** you have to remove all elements from a `Collection`, use the `clear()` method. It's more efficient than `removeAll()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any object that doesn't have a reference to it is eligible for garbage collection, without you needing to do anything to it. So, ordinarily, `mHomeworks = HomeworkLab.get(getActivity()).getHomework();` is fine, since it will clear the reference to the old object and allow the memory to be reclaimed (assuming it's not reference anywhere else).

The exception to this would be if mHomeworks was using up a large amount of your available memory before and after the new assignment. The old memory won't be available to be garbage collected until after the new assignment happens, so both objects will need to be in memory simultaneously for a brief period. If you don't have enough memory, this can lead to a slowdown, or OutOfMemory exception being thrown. In that case, `mHomeworks = null;` is sufficient to free up the memory. Of course, you would likely need to have VERY large lists for this to matter.

What you definitely don't want to do is `mHomeworks.removeAll(mHomeworks);` since that will result in a concurrent modification of the list. Internally, it will remove something from the list while iterating over it, breaking the iterator and throwing an exception.

Comment: Very good answer.  I would like to add that the exception would be very exceptional and is practically never required.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly could but java does handle its own garbage collection and will remove unused memory when more is needed. For more on how that works check out:

[How does the Garbage Collection mechanism work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774357/how-does-the-garbage-collection-mechanism-work)

Answer (score 0):

I would look at this question:

[In Java, how is an Array of objects garbage collected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627836/in-java-how-is-an-array-of-objects-garbage-collected)

Basically my understanding of the garbage collection mechanism is as such:

Do you have a reference to the data?

Yes - no gc.
   No - do gc.

So in your case this call:

```
mHomeworks = HomeworkLab.get(getActivity()).getHomework();//update list
```

Would take care of removing the reference to the old data.  Thus it would be GC'd automatically.  Doing what you're doing won't help or hinder that process too noticeably in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

You're updating the reference of mHomeworks every time you call

```
 mHomeworks = HomeworkLab.get(getActivity()).getHomework();//update list
```

Java's garbage collection will automatically recycle objects that have no references to them. So, if you don't have any references to your old array, then it will be recycled for you.

In other words, these two lines are not needed:

```
 mHomeworks.removeAll(mHomeworks);
 mHomeworks = null;
```

See @kuntajts 's link for more information